# Noclassdeffound error in quarkus application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, amazon-dynamodb, quarkus

I have created a pojo class marked with annotation @dynamodbBean but when I am running the test case ,I am getting noclassdeffound error for the pojo.I have also added the dynamodb enhanced sdk dependency in the pom.xml.I am getting this error when I am running test case and also in dev and normal mode.
Any help will be appreciated.

Getting follow exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/entities/UserEntity

```
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.constructNewBuilder(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:581)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.mapToItem(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:461)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.mapToItem(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:493)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.WrappedTableSchema.mapToItem(WrappedTableSchema.java:54)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.WrappedTableSchema.mapToItem(WrappedTableSchema.java:54)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.EnhancedClientUtils.readAndTransformSingleItem(EnhancedClientUtils.java:86)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.EnhancedClientUtils.lambda$readAndTransformPaginatedItems$0(EnhancedClientUtils.java:101)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.EnhancedClientUtils.readAndTransformPaginatedItems(EnhancedClientUtils.java:105)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.ScanOperation.transformResponse(ScanOperation.java:98)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.ScanOperation.transformResponse(ScanOperation.java:38)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.operations.PaginatedOperation.lambda$execute$0(PaginatedOperation.java:128)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.TransformIterator.next(TransformIterator.java:44)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.PaginatedItemsIterable$ItemsIterator.<init>(PaginatedItemsIterable.java:58)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.PaginatedItemsIterable.iterator(PaginatedItemsIterable.java:48)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.spliterator(Iterable.java:101)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.SdkIterable.stream(SdkIterable.java:34)
at com.abc.dao.impl.PoliciesRepositoryImpl.getClientPolicies(PoliciesRepositoryImpl.java:42)
at com.abc.dao.impl.PoliciesRepositoryImpl_ClientProxy.getClientPolicies(PoliciesRepositoryImpl_ClientProxy.zig:177)
```

Comment: Post the full error message here

Comment: added the error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.